# Does Windows 7 run acceptably on a 1 GB RAM Atom netbook?

Tags: windows-7, performance, netbook, compatibility

Does Windows 7 live well on a 1 GB RAM Atom netbook?  It's hard for me to try before I buy at the moment, so any advice from those that are already running Windows 7 would be appreciated.

Comment: It uses 1GB on my PC idle with nothing running!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I am using it on an ASUS N10 (1 GB of memory), and it seems to run as well as Windows XP did. There are a few minor driver issues, but nothing bad enough to make me revert to Windows XP.

Answer (score 16):

I've got it running on a 1 GB Atom Netbook and I think it runs fine. Admitedly I only use it for web browsing, but I can't say I've noticed any performance difference to when it was running Windows XP.

Comment: Yep, I have it running on my Dell Mini 9 happily.

Answer (score 2):

If [they](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Windows-7-Pentium-II,8110.html) are able to get it working on a Pentium II I think any current generation computer should be able to run it.

Edit: I have it running on a 6-year old HP-notebook. 2.4 Ghz Pentium 4, but only 512 MB RAM. Runs smoothly, only couldn't get my network drivers working, else I would have been able to review it's performance on websites and the like. But a 1 Gb Atom should be more than sufficient

Your biggest concern off course is what you can do with such a system.

Since if you try to multitask heavily or loads tons of superuser pages you can fill up any amount of RAM. 1 Gb should be fine for some browsing and IMing

Answer (score 1):

I believe Microsoft has a specific flavor of Windows 7 for netbooks (**Edit**: Looks like this was scrapped?) which is pretty stripped down.

I am not sure if a full-blown Windows 7 would be suitable for a 1gb RAM netbook...maybe if you went back to the retro displays and such.

http://www.tomsguide.com/us/Windows-seven-Netbook,review-1164.html

[Test Drive: Windows 7 on a Netbook](http://www.cnet.com/8301-18603_1-10142629-73.html)

Comment: Nope, Windows Starter Edition isn't for netbooks. Windows Ultimate or any SKU works great.

Answer (score 1):

I have it running on some Celeron's with a 1GB of RAM with no issues whatsoever. It is extremely fast and does not seem to be hampered.

You can still download the Windows 7 RC from Microsoft until the 15th of August to test it for yourself. You can download it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/home?os=nonwin7)

Answer (score 1):

I have an Acer Aspire One (160 GB HDD) with 1 GB of RAM and I run Photoshop CS3, Flash, Visual Studio and Windows 7.

Only because I found a tutorial and it was easy I added an additional 512 MB of RAM. But my system ran Windows 7 RC1 perfectly before adding the extra RAM.

With a netbook I noticed that I got a little extra boost by using a [ReadyBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost) drive as well.